# nGinX Forbidden still triggers request limit

Tags: nginx

I have some "deny" rules before the request limit config. If a blocked user (by the deny rules) is ddossing the site he still triggers the request limit and therefore creates thousands of log entries. Why? I expected that it will not go past the deny rules.

```
    include        /etc/nginx/blacklist.conf;
    limit_req zone=limit burst=3 nodelay;
```

The log shows a forbidden error and right after that hundreds of request limitation errors. That repeats over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

When nginx processes a request, it goes through [several phases](http://wiki.nginx.org/Phases). Among them : **preaccess** and **access** phases.
*Preaccess* is typically where `limit_req` works while access is where the `allow`/`deny` directives work. This means rate limiting is done **before** IP filtering if both directives are declared in the same context.

So if your will is to try to get some fail2ban alike process (given your other question return code 444) working directly in nginx using native directives, that's simply not possible by nature.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That is really sad. The main issue is indeed a fail2ban thing. We use CloudFlare and therefore can't use iptables to ban users, we use the CloudFlare API for that. When a DDos is incoming then fail2ban will use CloudFlare to ban the API, but it takes about a minute until the ban has fully applied, in this time thousands of requests still come through. Now the issue is that fail2ban goes through all of them and displays a "already banned" message. It takes a long time to go thourh them and therefore fail2ban takes a long time until it bans the next ip.

Comment: So we basically need a way to make sure that the log does not contain thousands of the "request limit exceeded" error for the same ip, otherwise that stops fail2ban from doing its job. Do you have any idea how we can do this? Tried to figure something out the last 2 days but nothing does work. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Michael In this case drop the `allow`/`deny` directives since this is cloudflare's job. Set some relevant overall [`limit_con`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html#limit_conn). I don't know what kind of business you are hosting though but that's very unlikely you would see thousands of connections from the same legitimate IP (mobile phone APs included). Set a proprer `limit_conn_status` code to indicate you have forbidden excessive connections (for instance code `429` : Too Many Requests). Now if you are under DDoS and not DoS the best thing you can do is scale out.

Comment: Sadly just setting a connection limit won't help us. Yesterday we hat 37Million requests coming in, generating 34TB of traffic. The log files are enourmes, thousands of different IPs with thousands of entries. We need a way to make sure that there is only one "request limit exceeded" entry for each IP, not a thousand, otherwise fail2ban will not keep up.

Comment: @Michael You can't fight DDoS at the web server level with only fail2ban as your weapon. Look at cloudflare's IUAM mode. Effective DDoS mitigation does not start at layer 7.

Comment: Not sure if you understand me correctly. Its not "fighting at the web server level". We just use fail2ban to issue the permanent CloudFlare bans, that would work perfectly fine if there wouldn't be thousands of the "request limit exceeded" messages in the logs for same IP addresses. Thats the only issue with the hole thing. Its not like that the server goes down or something like that.

Comment: I'm not new to DDoS you know... I understand very well. The reality is that you are waiting for layer 7 to be under pressure to mitigate at layer 3. Now, just rate limit your error logs if that's your big problem ? Rsyslog would do the job.

Comment: Yeah, the logs is pretty much the problem that it comes down to. In which way could you limit that? I guess that there is no way to have some settings to make sure that nginx only creates for entry for each ip in a given time frame, or something like that?

Comment: @Michael In nginx you can't but you can make your error_log to be appended to a specific [syslog](http://nginx.org/en/docs/syslog.html) facility instead of a log file (you'll need a recent nginx version, available since 1.7.1). Then you use syslog daemon daemon to rate limit syslog messages by PID, meaning that you will drop excessive log entries over the rate you specified, greatly limiting the whole thing.

Comment: Well, but this would then affect the whole log in general and therefore its random which entries make it it. There will be still multiple entries for the same IP. That would not fix anything (as far as i understand it) and would actually cause more problems. Is there no way to have nGInx check for banned IPs before the request limit takes place? That would be a workaround.

Comment: You are getting annoying. Why would it be worst at all ? You have a way to avoid logging thousands of message but simply a certain rate and I don't see how the hell you would think that on the thousands you log per IP you would loose all of them because you are rate limiting that's just silly. And why would it affect the **whole logs** since you can append to a dedicated facility or spin up a dedicated syslog daemon for that ? Now if you are willing to get nginx changes its behaviour then **just patch it**. I'm off of this, that just like speaking to a wall.

Comment: I'm sorry if you feel like that, thats clearly not my intention. What I mean is, lets say that there are 2 IPs attacking (just to demonstrate my question). The IP A just exhausted the log limit, now IP B starts to attack, but won't get logged as the other one just exhausted the limit.I know that it won't be this exact case cause it will most likely make it in after some time, but the fact that fail2ban needs about one second for each entry does not really allow me to still have multiple entries for the same IP. I'm not trying to be annoying, I just try to figure out a working solution. Sorry!

Comment: http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/. Input -> syslog. Filter->sleep. Output-> whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a bit old, but for anyone having this issue, the best solution I found for this case is to use a `map` with an `if` instead of the `deny` rules (although I try to avoid using `ifs` in nginx), because like [Xavier Lucas](https://serverfault.com/a/688197/415429) said:

> rate limiting is done before IP filtering

You can change your `blacklist.conf` file from:

```
deny 1.2.3.4;
```

to:

```
1.2.3.4 0;
```

Create a file `whitelist.conf`:

```
if ( $whitelist = 0 ) {
    return 403;
}
```

Then, in `nginx.conf`, include a map that whitelists every ip, except the ones in `blacklist.conf`:

```
http {
    geo $whitelist {
        /etc/nginx/blacklist.conf;
        default 1;
    }

    ...
}
```

Finally, also in `nginx.conf`, add before every server directive the `whitelist.conf` file:

```
server {
    server_name ...;
    listen 443 ssl;

    include /etc/nginx/whitelist.conf;

    ssl_certificate       /etc/ssl/bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key   /etc/ssl/server.key;

    ...
}

...
```

**The requests from the blacklisted ips will be returned immediatelly** and won't be logged in the error logs file.

You can also stop the requests from those ips from being logged in the access logs file with:

```
access_log /path/to/file if=$whitelist;
```